# Azure AD Bearer invalid_token error using Postman

Tags: api, azure, dynamics-crm, aws-lambda, adal

I am really new to Azure AD. I have read the Azure AD documentation which provides information on authentication and accessing web API's.

**What I want to do** : I want to use Dynamics CRM API to create a lead or contact through AWS Lambda. Meaning, whenever the Lambda function is ran, it should call the CRM API. The way I need to create a lead is with username and password creds included in Lambda. I am not sure which  application scenario I need to use when I am using AWS Lambda as the source to access the web api. I want to pass the user creds with POST request.

**Creating an application in Azure AD** : So, I am not sure which application type I need to use (Web API or Native App?). And what should be the sign-on URL or Redirect URI?

I have tried creating an application and use Postman as the temporary way just to test whether I can get the access token and access the web api. I could able to get the access token but when I tried to access the API it says

```
Bearer Error invalid_token, error validating token!
```

I have given enough permissions while creating application in Azure AD to access Dynamics CRM API. But still unable to access the API.

**POST request to get access token through Postman**:

```
request: POST
URL: https://login.windows.net/<tenant-id>/oauth2/token
Body:
grant_type: cliet_credentials
username: xxxxx
password: xxxxxxx
client_id: <app id>
resource: <resource> //I am not sure what to include here
client_secret: <secret_key>
```

I get the access token in the response. Sending the second POST request using the access token

```
request: POST
URL: https://xxx.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/accounts

Headers:
Content-type: application/json
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
OData-Version: 4.0
Authorization: Bearer <access_token>

Body:
{
    "name": "Sample Account",
    "creditonhold": false,
    "address1_latitude": 47.639583,
    "description": "This is the description of the sample account",
    "revenue": 5000000,
    "accountcategorycode": 1
}
```

It would really help me if I can get a bit more information on where I am stuck. I have already used my one week of time to get this done. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To do Server-to-Server (S2S) authentication  , the application is authenticated based on a service principal identified by an Azure AD Object ID value which is stored in the Dynamics 365 application user record. Please click [here](https://crmtipoftheday.com/2016/11/03/server-to-server-authentication-is-here/) and [here](http://phuocle.net/crm/dynamics-365-online-s2s-authentication-full-explain.aspx) for detail steps and code samples.

Comment: Thanks for the resources. After many trials, I was able to send a POST request to create a sample account using API. But this time I get the following in the response header.

`WWW-Authenticate →Bearer authorization_uri=https://login.windows.net/<tenant-id>/oauth2/authorize, resource_id=https://tenant-uri.api.crm.dynamics.com/`

Body still says `HTTP Error 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied`

Comment: Please firstly check [this document](http://phuocle.net/crm/dynamics-365-online-s2s-authentication-full-explain.aspx) for how to troubleshoot 'access is denied' error .

Comment: Thank you for the doc. But that's not what I am looking for. I don't want a login page. I want to pass the user credentials in the header section and then access the Web API.

Comment: Then the grant_type should be `password` and you don't need to provide client_secret parameter .read [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wushuai/2016/09/25/resource-owner-password-credentials-grant-in-azure-ad-oauth/) for more details for Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant .

Comment: @JayanthVishwanath, can you confirm you are specifying the right resource_id (https://<tenant-uri>.api.crm.dynamics.com/) and have configured your application for that permissions? Please update your question accordingly, as it stands, it indicates you don't know what to put for that parameter.